# Does redeployment of the same Cloud Function in firebase take up extra space?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I deployed a cloud function in firebase but instead of using a local emulator for testing purposes, I redeployed it several times to debug and test. After this, I see that my usage in the cloud storage in firebase is upwards of 500 MB although I have not stored any files in the Cloud Storage. Is this due to the multiple redeployments of the function? If yes, will deleting the cloud function free up this space or is there another way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, deploying a Cloud Function will take up more space in Cloud Storage.  There is a dedicated storage bucket for the build of the server images that get deployed.  You can see this for yourself in the [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser) for your project.  You can manually delete the content if you don't want to pay for the storage.

I don't think that deleting the function will also delete the storage, but you can try that for yourself and observe if it works the way you expect.

See also:

- [How to delete outdated Firebase Cloud function containers from GC Storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63884429/how-to-delete-outdated-firebase-cloud-function-containers-from-gc-storage)
- [will Cloud Function affect Firebase Storage bandwidth usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63697282/will-cloud-function-affect-firebase-storage-bandwidth-usage)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just to clarify, deploying and overwriting the same function multiple times will take up additional storage at each new deployment?

Comment: Yes, each deployment will store the source code and built server image separately.