# Is there a way to prevent Firebase Cloud Functions from using storage space in Firebase Storage?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I was looking at my Firebase Storage usage in my console and noticed the day I deployed my Cloud Functions there was a huge surge in storage usage. I see a new orange line appear called `us.artifacts.%PROJECT NAME%.appspot.com`. Why is my data related to Cloud Functions being stored in Firebase Storage? How do I prevent this? My problem with this huge surge in storage usage is I fear it could continue to increase causing me to pass the free tier limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files you see are part of the new deployment pipeline of Cloud Functions for Node.js 10 and higher. There is no way to prevent these files from being created while using Cloud Functions, although you can clean up outdated images.

Last time I checked, the files are actually creating in non-default buckets, which means there's no free quota on them. For most devs the storage cost adds up to a few dimes per month, but your mileage may vary of course.

For more on this see:

- the Firebase [FAQ on the Cloud Functions billing changes](https://firebase.google.com/support/faq#functions-pricing).
- [Firebase storage artifacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63578581/firebase-storage-artifacts/63580047#63580047)
- [Firebase Storage uses 490MB but I have no buckets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63893413/firebase-storage-uses-490mb-but-i-have-no-buckets/63893563#63893563)
- [Does redeployment of the same Cloud Function in firebase take up extra space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64469614/does-redeployment-of-the-same-cloud-function-in-firebase-take-up-extra-space/64469678#64469678)