# Deploying cloud function increased cloud storage bandwidth but no storage?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I was deploying very small size Cloud Function for testing, there were errors multiple times as I was doing egress network request which were not supported on the Spark plan and some other code related errors.

I upgraded to Blaze plan and was able to deploy the function successfully. Now suddenly my Bandwidth usage under Cloud Storage shot to 412 MB (41% of 1 GB of free tier). Going through other similar questions ([will Cloud Function affect Firebase Storage bandwidth usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63697282/will-cloud-function-affect-firebase-storage-bandwidth-usage)) I expected it to increase but is such high increase expected and how do I reduce it?

Also I found here that Cloud Storage also increases for some people: [Cloud Storage increasing on deploying Cloud Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59937542/can-i-delete-container-images-from-google-cloud-storage-artifacts-bucket). In my case the bytes stored are still 0, can someone explain this to me?

What I am doing is a payment gateway integration on my app and they have asked some code to be run on server side (currently I am doing it on app code itself for testing). I am moving this code to cloud functions. I am just afraid if there was this much increase for this small function and how much I will end up till this goes live?

Answer (score 0):

the storage usage is just for the deployment of the function that is the deployment process. The reason you are seeing 0 storage is because the storage bandwidth is related to deployment (if the function itself does not use storage API), so it will not increase.

you can limit the capacity and quotas for any GCP products by using a budget available in GCP. with that you can set a budget for any Google products by setting an alert. Please refer to this link [here](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/budgets): In this way you can set up a limit inturn you can monitor the limits as well.

And also for the Cloud function you can use the above link to set the budget or you can use refer to this [link](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator). To estimate the budget for the Cloud Functions.

For the Firebase, Please have a look [here](https://firebase.google.com/pricing) for Firebase pricing.Hope this works for you!