# firebase storage usage is high while its empty

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

**Thank you I got the  problem regarding the storage, But what about bandwidth?**

I have a firebase project, My storage usage is high while actually is empty.
When it was not empty it has only 2 image with 2MB, I never had any thing there.
Also the bandwidth is very high while I am still in testing mode.
see the attached images can any one explain pleas? [image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: If you're using Cloud Functions, most likely there's an additional Cloud Storage bucket associated with your project that contains the container images that were created during your deploy of those functions. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63578581/firebase-storage-artifacts/63580047#63580047/

Comment: For the bandwidth usage, check [Will Cloud Function affect Firebase Storage bandwidth usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63697282/13130697)